# Create a "time period" index variable based on year R

Tags: r, dplyr

I wish to construct a variable that assigns an ID value for each ID/year combination so that the new variable counts the time period rather than simply list the year.

This is what I am going for:

| id | year | time_period |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2001 | 1 |
| 1 | 2002 | 2 |
| 1 | 2004 | 3 |
| 2 | 2005 | 1 |
| 2 | 2006 | 2 |
| 3 | 2002 | 1 |
| 3 | 2005 | 2 |
| 4 | 2004 | 1 |
| 4 | 2008 | 2 |
| 4 | 2009 | 3 |
| 4 | 2011 | 4 |

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4), year = c(2001, 
2002, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2002, 2005, 2004, 2008, 2009, 2011), 
    time_period = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

How might I do this? I prefer a tidyverse solution but whatever is easiest will suffice.

Update: I tried the following:

```
df %>% group_by(ID, year) %>% mutate(time_period = sequence(n()))
```

but this did not generate the desired result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to group by id only and then create the sequence, if you can turn the year into a `factor` and then convert to integer/numeric:

```
df %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   mutate(time_period_factor = as.integer(factor(year, levels = sort(unique(year)))))

# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   id [4]
#      id  year time_period time_period_factor
#   <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>              <int>
# 1     1  2001           1                  1
# 2     1  2002           2                  2
# 3     1  2004           3                  3
# 4     2  2005           1                  1
# 5     2  2006           2                  2
# 6     3  2002           1                  1
# 7     3  2005           2                  2
# 8     4  2004           1                  1
# 9     4  2008           2                  2
#10     4  2009           3                  3
#11     4  2011           4                  4
#12     4  2009           3                  3
```

New data with a duplicated year for one site

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4,4), year = c(2001, 
                                                                 2002, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2002, 2005, 2004, 2008, 2009, 2011,2009), 
               time_period = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4,3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                      -12L))
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for my full dataset. I created a "fake" dataset to use as an example, and the code works fine for that, but it is creating `time_period_rank` values like 1.5 and 4.5. Any thoughts as to what may be causing this? I cannot share the full dataset. I changed the ties.method argument and still am not getting the correct results

Comment: the 1.5 and 4.5 are due to ties in the ranking, which is to say you have years that are duplicated per (some) site. You can change the way `rank` handles ties with the `ties.method`.

Comment: Yes, I tried changing the `ties.method`, but I am still getting incorrect results for come of my id's. I have an example where, for the same id, `time_period_rank` is 1 for the year 2002, 2 for the two observations in 2004, but 4 for the one in 2006. However, the one in 2006 should be 3, not 4.